# tkinter gui window is not opening but the code is running with exit code 0

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def main_account_screen():

    main_screen = Tk()  
    main_screen.geometry("300x250")  
    main_screen.title("Account Login")  


    Label(text="Choose Login Or Register", bg="blue", width="300", height="2", font=("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()


    Button(text="Login", height="2", width="30").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()


    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30").pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()  

    main_account_screen()  

    tk.mainloop()
```

I'm not getting any GUI when I run the .py file. Can anyone help me why this doesn't work. I'm using Pycharm but I have also tried running the program with the regular python interpreter.

Comment: The indentation on the last 2 lines makes them part of the `main_account_screen()` function so they are never getting executed. Move them out of the function.

Comment: You can also delete the last line `tk.mainloop()` since you have `main_screen.mainloop()`.

Comment: thank you! fixed it and now its running